# How to add a line break in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

I need to add text to a webpage using javascript so I've done it as follows

```js
// Create name as h1
var h = document.createElement('h1');
var t = document.createTextNode('Austin Chandler');
h.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(h);

// Formatting h1 tag
document.querySelector('h1').style.color = 'red';
document.querySelector('h1').style.fontFamily = 'Tahoma';
document.querySelector('h1').style.textAlign = 'center';

// Line break
document.write('\n');

// Create course and section number as h2
var h_2 = document.createElement('h2');
var t_2 = document.createTextNode('WEB 115 - Section 0001');
h.appendChild(t_2);
document.body.appendChild(h_2);

// Formatting h2 tag
document.querySelector('h2').style.color = 'red';
document.querySelector('h2').style.fontFamily = 'Garamond';
document.querySelector('h2').style.fontStyle = 'italics';
document.querySelector('h2').style.textAlign = 'center';
```

`document.write('\n');` only adds a small space between my text "Austin Chandler" and "WEB 115 - Section 0001" not a line break.

Output should look as follows: 
Austin Chandler 
WEB 115 - Section 0001

The current output looks like this: 
Austin Chandler WEB 115 - Section 0001

What can I do to add a line break?

Comment: Did you tried `<br>`?

Comment: @iamdlm I did try that. It didn't seem to work. Unless I'm doing it wrong. I added it after my name for ```var t``` and tried using ```document.write('<br>');``` under the line break comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));` instead of \n

But also, you are adding all your text to h1. You want the second text in the h2 element:

```js
// Create name as h1
var h = document.createElement('h1');
var t = document.createTextNode('Austin Chandler');
h.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(h);

// Formatting h1 tag
document.querySelector('h1').style.color = 'red';
document.querySelector('h1').style.fontFamily = 'Tahoma';
document.querySelector('h1').style.textAlign = 'center';

// Line break
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

// Create course and section number as h2
var h_2 = document.createElement('h2');
var t_2 = document.createTextNode('WEB 115 - Section 0001');

// here change h to h2:
h_2.appendChild(t_2);


document.body.appendChild(h_2);

// Formatting h2 tag
document.querySelector('h2').style.color = 'red';
document.querySelector('h2').style.fontFamily = 'Garamond';
document.querySelector('h2').style.fontStyle = 'italics';
document.querySelector('h2').style.textAlign = 'center';
```

Comment: Guess @Nicolas was faster, document.write('<br>'); should work just as well.

Comment: Yes it does, after I corrected my mistake of the h to h_2 it worked.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML, line break are `<br>` and since your Javascript is writing HTML, you need to use `<br>`.

Also, all of you text is in `h1` because you were adding the second text to the wrong element. See bellow.

```js
// Create name as h1
var h = document.createElement('h1');
var t = document.createTextNode('Austin Chandler');
h.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(h);

// Formatting h1 tag
document.querySelector('h1').style.color = 'red';
document.querySelector('h1').style.fontFamily = 'Tahoma';
document.querySelector('h1').style.textAlign = 'center';

// Line break
document.write('<br>');

// Create course and section number as h2
var h_2 = document.createElement('h2');
var t_2 = document.createTextNode('WEB 115 - Section 0001');
   // you were adding the second text to the first element
h_2.appendChild(t_2);
document.body.appendChild(h_2);

// Formatting h2 tag
document.querySelector('h2').style.color = 'red';
document.querySelector('h2').style.fontFamily = 'Garamond';
document.querySelector('h2').style.fontStyle = 'italics';
document.querySelector('h2').style.textAlign = 'center';
```

Comment: Using ```document.write('<br>');```? For me that only creates the output as "Austin ChandlerWEB 115 - 0001"

Comment: @Austinwc0402 Yeah, if you inspect the element, you see there is now a `<br>` in the source. There still something wrong with your logic and i'm trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `<br>`. It would add a break

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<script>
    document.write ('line1');
    document.write ('<br />');
    document.write ('line2');
</script>
```